# how can I write a loop to repeat checking element text until it changes?

Tags: robotframework

i need to write a code like below:

- verify element text before execute action1
- execute action1
- verify element text change/update after execute action1

It will take a minute for element text to change/update, how can i write a loop to check until element text changes ?

is there a keywords that i can use for this or how can I use a loop in robot framework ?

Answer (score 2):

There's a keyword in the SeleniumLibrary just for that - [Wait Until Element Contains](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Wait%20Until%20Element%20Contains), if you know the target string.

If you don't know it - there is a reciprocal keyword `Wait Until Element Does Not Contain` on which you can pass the old value.

---

And if these won't serve the purpose for some reason, you can code your specific version; the algorithm is:

1. Get the current value
2. Get the current time (with milliseconds precision) and call it start_time; store the same value in another var, current_time
3. Start a `WHILE` loop, with condition `(current_time - start_time) < some_max_wait_time` value; inside the loop:

   1. Get the current value, and compare it to the desired (or - to be different than the starting one in 1.)
   2. If true/success - `BREAK` the while loop
   3. If false - `Sleep` for 100/300/1000 ms (whatever is the reasonable time for your context)
   4. Get the current time and store it in current_time
   5. Go back to 3.
4. You'll have to know outside of the while loop did the check succeeded - if the loop was the last thing in the keyword you can just call `RETURN` in it; if not - you can use a boolean value to communicate that,and `FAIL` if not.

A variation of this would be to have as the while condition `current_value == 'desired one'` (or `!= 'staring one'`) and check has it crossed the max wait inside the loop, and call `Fail` if so.

This approach is more generic - I for example use it for checks on DB changes, files, message bus systems etc.

Comment: Alternative option is to use built-in keyword Wait Until Keyword Succeeds.

Comment: @BobMeliev that's true and is quite applicable for simple asserts. The problem with it is if you have one getter ("get db value") and another to verify ("should be equal ${db_value} my value"), you have to create a keyword just for that, to pass to `Wait Until Keyword Succeeds`.